# Steam Ubuntu 14.04 libGL.so.1 Bumblebee

Tags: 14.04, steam, bumblebee, libraries

I'm trying to install Steam on Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm missing a library

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

I have installed `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` but it still doesn't work
Using the nvidia card with bumblebee (`optirun`) it starts normally, thus I don't know what this could be.

I have also Ubuntu 13.04 and I can start steam with the intel card without any problems, and use optirun only when launching the games

Comment: Run in a terminal `locate libGL.so` and see if you have it. Then you can make a symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that Steam doesn't locate the library. Anyway, I solved it with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1`  :) Thank you

Comment: @DavidWinchester  this `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1`  worked me too. thanks for posting the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the optimus-based ssytems, you need generic mesa libraries for normal operation, and then bumblebee will switch to the NVidia's ones when needed.

These links are actually controlled by the alternatives mechanism.
To choose which one you would like to use invoke:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
There are 3 choices for the alternative i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/alt_ld.so.conf         8604      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf            500       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates-prime/alt_ld.so.conf   8603      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/alt_ld.so.conf         8604      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Be sure to set up the mesa one.

Same for the 64bit libraries:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
There are 3 choices for the alternative x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/ld.so.conf         8604      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates-prime/ld.so.conf   8603      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/ld.so.conf         8604      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf      500       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Reboot the system afterwards and try launching steam again.

Comment: This is what I do, but there's no need to reboot. Just run `sudo ldconfig` instead and see if it worked.

Comment: Cyryl + Bruno method worked for me

Answer (score 7):

@DavidWinchester running this command (below) works well:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

thanks for posting the question

Comment: It is really not necessary to create any links with sudo in /usr. (Really, almost never). Use the update-alternatives answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, every time I tried to run steam it would tell me the libgl.so.1 error. All I did was type this into terminal and open steam back up and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

If this works for you, please upvote. Also, if you experience more issues, let me know in the replies. I will be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Your solution is in the webpage above. Uninstall all current nvidia drivers you have and install those ones.